# change event of model.save() firing twice in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I've made view to listen to model changes. When there is change in model render function will be called and alert window will be prompted. But it is coming twice that means render function is calling twice because of two change events.

**WineDetails View**
app.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

```
    template:_.template($('#tpl-wine-details').html()),

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);

    },
    render:function (eventName) {
  if(eventName)alert("changed")
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

     events:{
        "change input":"change",
        "click .save":"saveWine",
        "click .delete":"deleteWine"
    },
    change:function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        console.log('changing ' + target.id + ' from: ' + target.defaultValue + ' to: ' + target.value);
        // You could change your model on the spot, like this:
        // var change = {};
        // change[target.name] = target.value;
        // this.model.set(change);
    },
    saveWine:function () {
        this.model.set({
            name:$('#name').val(),
            grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
            country:$('#country').val(),
            region:$('#region').val(),
            year:$('#year').val(),
            description:$('#description').val()
        });
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            var self = this;
         app.router.wineList.create(this.model,{wait:true,success:function(){
                 app.router.navigate('wines/'+self.model.id,false);
         }});//add event,request event on collection will be triggered

        } else {
            this.model.save();//change event,request event on model will be triggered
        }
        return false;
    },
onClose:function()
    {
        alert("onclose");
        this.model.unbind("change",this.render);
    }
```

And its not because of zombie view because i've this following code

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close=function()
{
    alert("closing view "+this);
    if(this.beforeClose){
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    if(this.onClose){
        this.onClose();
    }

}
```

please tell me what is wrong in this code. Thank u :)

Comment: FYI you don't really need such a `close` method since Bacbone 0.9.9 which introduced (long ago) the `listenTo` and `stopListening` methods that allow a tracking of the listeners and therefore to clean them with the `remove` method. (I think you followed Derick Bailey's method which was written way before the 0.9.9)

Comment: Ya i'am following Derick Bailey's method.But why is change event firing twice?? Any idea??

Comment: See my answer, add more information if that's not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, as you didn't provide the information regarding your `Model#save` call, I'll assume it's the one within your view. I'll also assume the problem doesn't come from *zombie views* because you're following an outdated method for that. I'll make a guess here about what's probably happening:

```
this.model.set({
  name:$('#name').val(),
  grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
  country:$('#country').val(),
  region:$('#region').val(),
  year:$('#year').val(),
  description:$('#description').val()
});
// ...
this.model.save();
```

Ok, the first part (the `set` method) will trigger a first `change` event.
The second part, the `save` method *may* trigger another change. Another `set` will indeed be done with the attributes sent back from the server.

Possible solution to a possible problem:
`save` can be passed attributes, and a `wait` flag to postpone the use of the `set` method until the server responds:

```
this.model.save({
  name:$('#name').val(),
  grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
  country:$('#country').val(),
  region:$('#region').val(),
  year:$('#year').val(),
  description:$('#description').val()
}, {wait: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try it by creating always a new instance of your model like :

```
var wine = new WineModel({
    name:$('#name').val(),
    grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
    country:$('#country').val(),
    region:$('#region').val(),
    year:$('#year').val(),
    description:$('#description').val()
});
```

And then save it like :

```
wine.save(null, success: function(model){
    // do your call action on call back
},
beforeSend: function() {
    // before save 
}
error: function(model, errors) {
    // on error occurred
});
```